# React native fetch doesn't resolve or reject API request

Tags: react-native, fetch

I always get correct response from this request in my browser console:

```
fetch('http://178.62.66.29:8080/api/v1/auth/1/2', {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responsejson =>  console.log(responsejson))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

But when I use the exact same code in React native (Android) the fetch function doesn't resolve or reject anything. The thing is, sometimes the fetch function works (Like 1/10) which makes this problem even more confusing to me.

Comment: is `http://178.62.66.29:8080/` the correct domain?

Comment: Also you can turn debuggin on in the console to see the error messages. What does it show?

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense it is the correct domain, there is nothing in the console since it never reaches .then or .catch

Comment: it is almost certainly the incorrect domain or port, try using an API client like postman to debug issues like this

Comment: Are you sure that fetch is even called in your app? (No offence, just the most likely issue from what we can see here.)

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I already did all of this. As I said before, it does fetch sometimes but not always, on the other hand it always works in postman or chrome console.

Comment: @JannikS. Yes, I tried it hundred of times in many different ways and currently its on onPress of a button. It displays an indicator too (sets state loading) and the indicator never goes away because it never reaches then or catch, so I set a timeout for promise (Promise.race([req, timeout])) while I'm investigating.

Comment: what version of RN are you on? there used to be a bug where promises would hang indefinitely in debug but I'm pretty sure it's been fixed

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak react-native: 0.57.3 => 0.57.3

Comment: I know the syntax you're using is valid in the browser but maybe it's causing the issue, you could try moving your second `.then` to `response.json().then()`? Kind of a stretch but idk. Could also try adding axios `yarn add axios` or `npm install` and using that instead, see if you get better results? I prefer axios anyway since you don't have to resolve two promises. maybe check your antivirus / firewall and make sure port `8080` is good? just spitballing at this point but I hope you can get it sorted

Comment: Hey @Ali, did you manage to resolve this? I"m facing the same issue now.

Comment: Nah I couldn't figure it out, sadly. I tried many different things but results were so random.